# Structural change analysis validity in case of auto-correlated data?

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, structural-change, environmental-data

I attempted to assess the "significance" of some environmental alteration through the identification of break points in a diagnostic time series (using R `strucchange` package).

The results (number of break-points were selected based on the BIC criterion) indicate a significantly altered regime prevailing since ~2008-present (and another, prevailing over 1984-1998).

[image]

My concern is that the original time series can not be considered strictly as random. In particular, it is significantly auto-correlated for lags of 1 and 2 years.

[image]

Therefore, I wondered :

- about the validity of concluding for a significant regime shift.
- if there is a way the method should be adapted to account for auto-correlated signals,
- or, alternatively, if some transformation may be operated on the time series before a similar analysis to ensure that the conclusion holds (for instance, the data are slightly non-normal, but a Box-Cox transformation does not change the conclusions).

Thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

(1) From your visualizations it is not 100% clear to me how you computed the ACF. Is this simply the ACF of the observed series? If so, then it might be that the structural changes are responsible for the autocorrelations. And possibly the ACF of the residuals (after accounting for breaks) is much closer to white noise. An example for the would be the famous `Nile` data.

```
bp <- breakpoints(Nile ~ 1)
cbind(
  Lag = 0:4,
  Nile = acf(Nile, plot = FALSE)$acf[1:5],
  Residuals = acf(residuals(bp), plot = FALSE)$acf[1:5]
)
##      Lag      Nile    Residuals
## [1,]   0 1.0000000  1.000000000
## [2,]   1 0.4984082  0.159856152
## [3,]   2 0.3845769 -0.007591145
## [4,]   3 0.3278604 -0.071648835
## [5,]   4 0.2391912 -0.139437593
```

Note that the ACF of the Nile series looks almost like an AR(1) but almost all autocorrelation vanishes after accounting for the break. (And the one-break model fits the data better than an AR(1) model.)

(2) If the autocorrelation is not too substantial you can simply estimate the model *without* accounting for it and then adjust the inference (e.g., confidence intervals) using a HAC covariance afterwards. See `example("RealInt", package = "strucchange")` for a worked example following Bai & Perron (2003).

(3) If the autocorrelation is more substantial, then it makes sense to account for it explicitly in an AR-type model and then try to detect changes in the AR coefficients. See the seatbelt example in `example("breakpoints", package = "strucchange")` for an illustration following Zeileis *et al.* (2003).

Comment: Indeed, it seems my case fall in your option (1), ie. all autocorrelation vanishes in the residuals from the three point break model. I see therefore no reason to look for (3). Thanks a lot !